# stdvector inserting and erasing problem

Tags: c++, stdvector, openframeworks

I need to control the amount to touch points in my application, for this I am using a vector container and my basic setup is this:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::touchDown(ofTouchEventArgs &touch){
    isTouching = true;

    touchPoints.push_back( ofVec2f( touch.x, touch.y ) );
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::touchMoved(ofTouchEventArgs &touch){
    for ( int i = 0; i < touchPoints.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( touch.id == i ) {
            touchPoints[i] = ofVec2f( touch.x, touch.y );
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::touchUp(ofTouchEventArgs &touch){
    isTouching = false;

    int i = 0;
    for ( vector<ofVec2f>::iterator iter = touchPoints.begin(); iter != touchPoints.end(); ) {
        //int i = std::distance( touchPoints.begin(), iter );
        cout << "i: " << i << endl;
        if ( touch.id == i ) {
            iter = touchPoints.erase( iter );
        }
        i++;
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

But when I move up a finger the app freezes, so there most be something wrong in the touchUp(), any ideas?

Comment: Well, have you tried debugging it?  Like with `printf`/`cout`?

Comment: Yes the loop never ends "i" keeps incrementing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many things: First off, you cannot modify (erase/insert) a container and expect iterators to remain valid!

Let's see. I want to modify `touchMove` as well:

```
void testApp::touchMoved(const ofTouchEventArgs & touch)
{
  if (touch.id < touchPoints.size())
    touchPoints[touch.id] = ofVec2f(touch.x, touch.y);
}
```

Next, the big one:

```
void testApp::touchUp(const ofTouchEventArgs & touch)
{
  if (touch.id < touchPoints.size())
    touchPoints.erase(touchPoints.begin() + touch.id);
}
```

Basically `touch.id` **is** just the index in the vector, so we can use that directly. To erase an element from the middle, we just call `erase` on the corresponding iterator. Since vector has random access iterators, we can say `begin() + touch.id` in constant time.

**Update:** Actually I think your code is broken: After you erase an element from the vector, the other elements move up, so you will lose the association between `touch.id` and the container element! What's needed is, you guessed it, an **associative** container:

```
struct testApp
{
  std::map<int, ofVec2f> touchPoints;
  bool isTouching;

  void touchDown(const ofTouchEventArgs & touch)
  {
    isTouching = true;
    touchPoints[touch.id] = ofVec2f(touch.x, touch.y);
  }

  void touchMoved(const ofTouchEventArgs & touch)
  {
    touchPoints[touch.id] = ofVec2f(touch.x, touch.y);
  }

  void touchUp(const ofTouchEventArgs & touch)
  {
    isTouching = false;
    touchPoints.erase(touch.id);
  }
};
```

Comment: remove-erase is clearly more idiomatic, but I don't think the OP's `touchUp` is relying on any old iterators remaining valid.

Comment: @Oli: Sorry, remove-erase doesn't actually apply, I got that wrong in my first draft. This is just a simple erase. Actually I think this code is broken, as after the erase there won't be a connection between the index and `touch.id` anymore.

Comment: @Kerrek associative container? like map?

Comment: @Kereek awesome, thanks a lot and way much easier than I thought

Comment: @Richardo: That's C++ -- you can tell that you're doing it right when it feels "beautiful" :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you've done `iter=touchPoints.erase(iter)` you shouldn't then do `++iter`; you've already moved on to the next item.

Comment: Even `erase(iter++)` doesn't work in vectors, because `erase` invalidates *all* iterators past the erasure point.